# scala: compare types of inner class objects

Tags: scala

How do I know if two objects of inner class have the same runtime type?
In the example below I expect to see the class of aa.getClass == a.Inner and ba.getClass == b.Inner, but in fact they are both Outer.Inner and equal.

```
class Outer{
      class Inner{}
    }

    val a = new Outer
    val b = new Outer

    val aa = new a.Inner
    val ab = new a.Inner
    val ba = new b.Inner

    val res1 = aa.getClass == ba.getClass
    val res2 = aa.isInstanceOf[ab.type ]

    scala>      |      | defined class Outer

    scala> a: Outer = Outer@550a1967

    scala> b: Outer = Outer@5f9678e1

    scala> aa: a.Inner = Outer$Inner@70a36a66

    scala> ab: a.Inner = Outer$Inner@1dd6d4b7

    scala> ba: b.Inner = Outer$Inner@2e61d218

    scala> res1: Boolean = true

    scala> res2: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... aa.getClass == a.Inner and ba.getClass == b.Inner, but in fact they are both Outer.Inner and equal

This is not true. `Inner` is a class member and is *unique to its parent instance* of `Outer`. This means that both `a` and `b` have their own unique version of `Inner`, which are incompatible types. So `a.Inner` is *not* the same type as `b.Inner`, and therefore an `a.Inner` can never be equal to a `b.Inner`. I cannot assign one for the other:

```
scala> val z: a.Inner = aa       // aa is a.Inner, so this is ok
z: a.Inner = Outer$Inner@575d06dd

scala> val z: b.Inner = aa       // aa is not b.Inner, so it fails to compile
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a.Inner
 required: b.Inner
       val z: b.Inner = aa
                        ^
```

`getClass` just isn't very useful here.

We can prove this with reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def tpeOf[A](a: A)(implicit tt: TypeTag[A]) = tt.tpe

scala> tpeOf(aa) =:= tpeOf(ba) // different Outer parents
res24: Boolean = false

scala> tpeOf(aa) =:= tpeOf(aa) // Same instance
res25: Boolean = true

scala> tpeOf(aa) =:= tpeOf(ab) // Same Outer parent
res26: Boolean = true
```

On the other hand, you can use `Outer#Inner` to specify that you don't care which `Outer` your `Inner` type belongs to.

```
val x: Outer#Inner = aa
val x: Outer#Inner = ab
val x: Outer#Inner = ba
```

So as stated by @BenReich, you could use `aa.isInstanceOf[Outer#Inner]` to check if you have any of those types, and they would all return `true`.

`ab.type` means something completely different. `ab.type` is a singleton type that contains nothing but `ab`. So naturally then, `aa.isInstanceOf[ab.type]` must be false, because `aa` is not `ab`, regardless of whether or not they are both `a.Inner`.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that they are both assignable to `Outer#Inner`

Comment: Thanks! Strange that we need to write a custom method to use when comparing inner class objects...

Comment: @Yegor Note that you *can* do `ab.isInstanceOf[Outer#Inner]` with the desired effect.

Comment: @Yegor My custom method is more so to make up for my lack of knowledge of the reflection library. There might be a method that already does it, but I just wanted a quick way to compare the types using what I already knew about `TypeTag`s